# I am able to SSH to VM but unable to PING in centOS8

Tags: networking, ssh, ping, centos8

I am able to SSH to a VM but unable to PING it.

Even though I have stopped firewall I am facing same issue.
Does anybody have any ideas?
Also port forwarding is enabled for HTTPS service on that machine.
I wanted to open one port on that machine.

Comment: are u using ec2 instances ?

Comment: no it's not an EC2 instance

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check is there any kernel level block for ICMP request.

Comment: Can you please share a way to do it for centos8 ?

Comment: Inside your VM use the command -->                                                                                   cat /etc/sysctl.conf | grep net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all  <---                                                                                                                                   if the output is shown as>>> net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all=1  , then ICMP request is blocked.   Remove that line  or NULL it , which allows ICMP  request.

Comment: sysctl.conf file has only comments written inside it.

Comment: Please share the output of this command--> cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all

Comment: # sysctl settings are defined through files in
# /usr/lib/sysctl.d/, /run/sysctl.d/, and /etc/sysctl.d/.
#
# Vendors settings live in /usr/lib/sysctl.d/.
# To override a whole file, create a new file with the same in
# /etc/sysctl.d/ and put new settings there. To override
# only specific settings, add a file with a lexically later
# name in /etc/sysctl.d/ and put new settings there.
#
# For more information, see sysctl.conf(5) and sysctl.d(5).